# What's the correct way to include shared libraries across multiple projects (for purpose of CI)

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, dependencies, cruisecontrol.net

I have a project structure that looks like the following:

- [Solution Name]

  - doc (documentation)
  - extlib (external libraries depended on by multiple source projects)

    - [Nunit]
    - [FluentValidation]
    - etc.
  - src (source code)

    - Solution file
    - [C# library project folder]
    - [MVC 3 Project folder]
    - [NUnit Test Project folder]

I have a build process in CruiseControl .NET for each project. However, for example, when I include FluentValidation in my library project from it's location off of "extlib", CruiseControl doesn't know about this directory and throws an error.

I wanted to keep all my external library in one place (same versions, etc.), but is this really necessary?

I'm betting there's a better way to do this (NuGet packages maybe?) What's the best-practices alternative to the way I've attempted to set up my build process here?

**Update:** FYI, I'm aware of why the error is caused. It's caused because the extlib folder is above my source projects, but I only pull the source projects in their artifact folders for the build. So, to revise the question, I'm wondering if it's a better route to reconfigure all my CruiseControl setup, or if it would be better to utilize NuGet packages within each project, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

-- 
Sean

Comment: Whats thw ccnet error? Can you paste a snippet from your csproj file.

Comment: The ccnet error is that it doesn't find the FluentValidation library. Which again, makes perfect sense because I'm referencing fluentValidation from my extlib folder, which ccnet does not have available to it. I think it might have to do with the way I'm pulling source code. For each project, I'm pulling its folder separately. I should pull the whole repo and check folders for changes, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more natural for CruiseControl.NET to work at the solution level. I would suggest checking out your entire repository and using different triggers per project (as you state in your own comment:)).

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same situation at work.
We used to have a single network place where we put all the third libraries used by our project and the output of our projects dlls (Toolkits, Logging etc...).

What we have done is ECI (Enterprise Continuous Integration). You can read about it [here](http://mikebroberts.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/enterprise-continuous-integration-using-binary-dependencies.pdf).
We discussed it on the ccnet-user mailing list, the topic is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/ccnet-user/browse_thread/thread/a7da080d2dbd0437/08d732e321842bcd?lnk=gst&q=benjamin+baumann#08d732e321842bcd).

Basically, your extlibs are your the source control folder and the CI tool is updating them automatically when changed are made and validated (by unit tests for example).

The pros :

- You can make changes in your basic bricks without testing the effects on every project that has a dependency to it, cc.net validate it for you.
- You can go on developping on big projects and even if the newer version of your small bricks is (temporarily) incompatible

The cons :

- Increase the size of your source control repository
- ???

As for the feedbacks, some developers needed time to understand the process but they all are much happier with the new system, they can commit changes and see within minutes if they have broken another project or not. They deployments are now much calmer!

**EDIT :**

Sorry, I misread your question, but my feedback is still useful. Why don't you check out the files at your  "Solution Name" node instead of the src one?

Answer (score 0):

The CCNET doesn't have to know about the external library as entry of reference to the external library would be in each individual .CSPROJ file. Could you make sure below things

- Make sure that the extlib folder exist in expected location
- Make sure that all the projects
  referring to external dll has proper entries wrt extlib 
  in .CSPROJ file (you can edit and
  check this out).

Comment: Hi Kumar, please see the update I just made. That is most definitely the issue, and I should have worded it better in my question. It just brought up the question of theory -- should I change how my CCNet projects are pulled / built, or should I utilize NuGet packages in each project that needs them? It's more of a question on how to proceed from there. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I would suggest reconfigure the ccnet setup to point it to properly as you are very close to getting it done rather than investing time in setting NuGet pckg all over again (although it is good approach to use otherwise).